# unable to specialize template from another namespace

Tags: c++, templates, opencv

I have forked out of opencv and when I try to modify once of the templated code for a specialization, within my namespace, I get the error :

```
make -k 

[100%] Building CXX object object_detection.cpp.o
In file included from object_detection.cpp:1:0:
object_detection.h:370:75: error: specialization of 'void cv::Ptr<_Tp>::delete_obj() [with _Tp = CvHaarClassifierCascade]' in different namespace [-fpermissive]
object_detection.h:370:30: error:   from definition of 'void cv::Ptr<_Tp>::delete_obj() [with _Tp = CvHaarClassifierCascade]' [-fpermissive]
```

I understand that I should not be able to specialize template code in different namespace but is there a way out ?

Comment: What's wrong with specializing it in the `cv` namespace? Just wrap your specialization with `namespace cv { }`

Comment: Just put it in the same namespace? Surround your specialization with `namespace cv { (specialization here) }`

Comment: Yeah, I am able to do that. I was just wondering if I could use that specialization only in 1 namespace. But I'll go ahead with this. Thx

Answer (score 0):

1. Reopen their namespace, and specialize in it.
2. For functions, if it is faithfully used via ADL, create an override in a parameter's namespace.
3. Check if the source template is using a traits class or other similar technique, which you can intercept.